# How to make “Stay-On-Top” Menu in IE6 and above?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make menu on top with fixed position and content scroll enable in **IE6** and above.
I have tried with jsfiddle.net code but it has css property position:fixed; which is not supporting to IE6.

sample code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Dynamic Top Menu Positioning - jsFiddle demo</title>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">


  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

  <style type='text/css'>
    .menu {
    background:#345;
    color:#FFF;
    height:2em;
    padding:.5em;
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    width:100%;
}
.fixed {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
}
  </style>



<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
/* Dynamic top menu positioning
 *
 */

var num = 50; //number of pixels before modifying styles

$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
        $('.menu').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('.menu').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});

//USE SCROLL WHEEL FOR THIS FIDDLE DEMO
});//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
  <div class="menu">Menu</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />(Bottom!)

</body>


</html>
```

Below links not supporting for IE6
[scroll-fix-header-jquery-facebook](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/scroll-fix-header-jquery-facebook/) and 
[nagging-menu-with-css3-and-jquery](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/nagging-menu-with-css3-and-jquery/index.html)

Could anyone help me to achieve this in **IE6 and above**

Comment: IE6 is dead, let it go

Comment: Although a workaround is possible with HTML and CSS alone, I’d also recommend not going there – it has some drawbacks and is not worth the hassle, unless you absolutely _“have to”_ support IE6 (which you shouldn’t). People still using IE6 for whatever reason are used to a very “limited internet” when it comes to modern effects and layout sugar – so a menu that just sits on top of the page and scrolls away is just fine.

Comment: Hi, We have some machines where we have to execute our exe but we don't have permission to update IE, as exe displays result in windows web browser control, we must have to stick with windows current IE ie IE6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got solution from website [Fixed Position DIV in IE6](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1740-Building-A-Fixed-Position-Bottom-Menu-Bar-ala-FaceBook-.htm)